# Function headerMode not working or dont seem to exist

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I just got to this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { LoginScreen } from '../pages/LoginScreen';
import { CreateAccount } from '../pages/CreateAccount';

const stackRoutes = createStackNavigator();

const AppRoutes: React.FC = () => (
    <stackRoutes.Navigator
        headerMode="none"
        screenOptions={{cardStyle: {backgroundColor: '#FFF'}, }}
    >

        <stackRoutes.Screen
            name="LoginScreen"
            component={LoginScreen}
        />
        <stackRoutes.Screen
            name="CreateAccount"
            component={CreateAccount}
        />

    </stackRoutes.Navigator>
)

export default AppRoutes;
```

And reports an error in "headerMode = "none", i already made some searchs but i couldnt find what exactly is wrong.
Should it be defined in some other way? Or is there something i should have installed

What i already have installed :
yarn add @react-navigation/native,
npx expo install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context,
yarn add @react-navigation/native-stack,
yarn add @react-navigation/stack and
npx expo install react-native-gesture-handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made some changes and its working fine now, instead of using `headerMode` I'm using `headerShown` in the `screenOptions`, so the code will look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { LoginScreen } from '../pages/LoginScreen';
import { CreateAccount } from '../pages/CreateAccount';

const stackRoutes = createStackNavigator();

const AppRoutes: React.FC = () => (
    <stackRoutes.Navigator
        /*headerMode="none"*/
        screenOptions={{cardStyle: {backgroundColor: '#FFF'}, headerShown: false}}
    >

        <stackRoutes.Screen
            name="LoginScreen"
            component={LoginScreen}
        />
        <stackRoutes.Screen
            name="CreateAccount"
            component={CreateAccount}
        />

    </stackRoutes.Navigator>
)

export default AppRoutes;
```

I don't know what was wrong, maybe with the new versions it changed, but it worked now.